# retrieve all objects key store in memcached in java

Tags: java, memcached

I stored some objects with key in memcached. But now I want to see which keys are stored in memcached.

How to retrieve all object keys stored in memcached in java?

I want to get keys which is more than 100 stored in memcached. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, [here's](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Can_I_iterate_the_items_of_the_memcached_server?) the explanation why:

> No. memcached doesn't support that and it's not a planned feature. It would be a relatively slow and blocking operation...

**UPDATE**

FAQ [How can you list all keys?](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ#How_can_you_list_all_keys?)

> With memcached, you can't list all keys. There is a debug interface, but that is not an advisable usage.

Comment: [here](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ#How_can_you_list_all_keys?) is the proper link for the FAQ referenced above.

Answer (score 1):

Memcached is a simple key/value storage, it does not have key list command, so it's not possible to fetch them. See the available commands [here](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands).

You should try a different storage if you want this, for example Redis has [`KEYS`](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command, with which you can fetch the stored keys, even with a specified pattern: `KEYS h?ll?*world`